# Python Clear Output in Atom (Mac)?

Tags: python, atom-editor

I know how to clear output when running the file in terminal, but as an added convenience is there a way to clear output when running the file from Atom's Script package?

For clarification, I am on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6, running Python 3.5.

And in case you came to this link by searching how to clear output in python, do it by

```
 print("\033[H\033[J")
```

This works in terminal, but not atom.

Comment: Do you mean how to clear the terminal or how to clear the area where the script command writes its output? the "clear" command works for the terminal in Atom.

Comment: Area where script writes output.

Comment: I was afraid you'd say that!  lol..  I'll keep looking...

Comment: @jmh any update?

Comment: no luck.  i'm still searching but can't find anything.. If I do I'll sure let you know.

Comment: that's ok don't worry.